# Gevent pywsgi server used with gunicorn?

Tags: flask, gunicorn, gevent

I have a flask app setup to use the gevent WSGIServer in my code. I am also running gunicorn on the command line to start the server.

Should I be using WSGI server in the code when also running with gunicorn? Currently looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer

application = Flask(__name__)

@application.route("/")
def hello():
    return "hello"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    WSGIServer(('', port), application).serve_forever()
```

On the command line I am running gunicorn like:

```
gunicorn -w 4 myapp:application
```

Do I need the WSGIServer in my code, or just run it as application.run() on the default flask server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Standalone WSGI Containers](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/deploying/wsgi-standalone/?highlight=standalone), The gunicorn and gevent.pywsgi are both WSGI Containers, and the gunicorn only reconize the entry named **application**.
So the code below `if __name__ == '__main__':` is not useful anymore.
If you want to use gevent,you could do:

```
gunicorn -k gevent -w 4 myapp:application
```